# Get the value of the active tap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to share the content of the view and the controller for the two tabs. I would like that when I click on a tab, in my controller I can get which tab was selected, if the "dashboard" tab or the "friends" tab.

How can I do it?

```
//same controller fot the tabs
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log("dash")
})

.state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "tabs.html"
  })


   //same template and controller
  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.friends', {
    url: '/friends',
    views: {
      'tab-friends': {
        templateUrl: 'tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/XmPNTx27gOvnpalrvVMj?p=preview

Comment: do you mean you have a variable and its value should get selected based on the state choosen?

Comment: yes!!! the tab active!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, and you can get the name of your tabs by your controller which define in `app.config` as state.

```
.state('tab.dash', {
  url: '/dash',
  views: {
    'tab-dash': {
      templateUrl: 'tab-dash.html',
      controller: 'DashCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('tab.friends', {
  url: '/friends',
  views: {
    'tab-friends': {
      templateUrl: 'tab-friends.html',
      controller: 'FriendsCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

only thing you miss is inject **view** and **controller** for friend tab, you should define it as top code, also your controllers will send you the name of the tab, when you select the tabs controller will console name.

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope) {
   console.log("DashCtrl")
})

.controller('FriendsCtrl', function($scope) {
   console.log("FriendsCtrl")
})
```

your codes is fine my friends, just simple mistake.